# Field multiple value form validation on "Add more" action

Tags: 7, entities

I've a field multiple value in my form (a node form in my case) and I want to add a custom validation on this field. So when the user click on "Add more" the validation run and if I set a drupal_set_error() in the validate function, no new element is created and then the error message is print to the front.

Can you help me to do this ?

Comment: Your "Add more" functionality is made with #ajax property of the Form API ?

Comment: Maybe. I'ts a node which contain a collection field with infinite values. Then when you fill the collection field and you can clic on "add more" to add a new collection field. And then I want when the user click on "add more" I can check the content of the last collection field to see if the user fill it right.

Comment: What's your condition of validation on your use case ?

Comment: To resume : custom. For more details, I have a select with a day to pick and 2 textfield which use an api to create a time field (I dont used a module because this restrict the validation). So I need to check If the fields are filled and if the first time field is lower than the second.